# SLURM How to start a script once per node

Tags: cluster-computing, slurm

I have a Big Cluster available through SLURM.
I want to start my script e.g. `./calc` on every requested node with a specified amount of cores. So for example on 2 nodes, 16 cores each.

I start with `sbatch` script

```
#SBATCH -N 2
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=16

srun -N 1 ./calc 2 &
srun -N 1 ./clac 2 &
wait
```

It doesn't work as intended though.
I tried many configurations of `--ntask` `--nodes` `--cpus-per-task` but nothing worked and I'm very lost.

I also don't understand the difference between task and CPUs in SLURM

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be a working solution. It turned out the most important thing was to define all parameters `nodes` `tasks` `cpus`

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH -N 2
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=16

srun -N 1 -n 1 -c 16 ./calc 2 &
srun -N 1 -n 1 -c 16 ./calc 2 &
wait
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you ask slurm to launch 16 tasks per node, on 2 nodes. At the end of the job, slurm will probably runs 8x(srun)x2 nodes tasks.

For your needs, you don't need to specify that you want 2 nodes specifically instead of the jobs have to run on 2 two different nodes.
For your example, run the following sbatch :

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --ntasks=2
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=16
#SBATCH --hint=nomultithread

srun <my program>
```

In this example, slurm will run 2 times the program with 16 cores. The nomultithread is optional and depends the cluster configuration. If the hyper-threading is activated, this will be 16 virtual cpus.